# Передача данных в переменную PHP после выполнения JS скрипта

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Есть скрипт который ищет инфу на своей же странице по классу, и заменяет содержимое.
Например:

```
<a class="test">тест</a>
```

Скрипт ищет класс test и заменяет слово тест на какое то рандомное. Какое - неизвестно, слово подставляется только после загрузки страницы. Вот как после загрузки страницы передать новое слово в переменную php? Сам пхп код находится в другом месте, ему можно дать ссылку на страницу где это слово меняется и выводится. Пробовал через XMLHttpRequest, но не очень понимаю принцип работы, как должен выглядеть PHP файл.
Через simple_html_dom он естественно хавает только первоначальное слово.
Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что можете  какое то значение из `js` просто взять и "засунуть" в `php` переменную? Если инфа просто ссылка, можете сохранить данные в куки и в `php` получить данную информацию.

Comment: Это не значение js, это просто слово обернутое в класс на странице. js видит класс test, и заменяет слово тест на слово привет, которое и показывается на странице, себе его никуда не сохраняя. вот это слово "привет" как раз необходимо вписать в переменную.

Comment: И что изменилось? ещё раз прочитайте мой комментарий.

Comment: Я правильно понял суть? : есть страница с html и яваскриптовым обработчиком щапуска парсинга. Есть пхп скрипт парсинга и возврата результата. Надо запустить пхп на нужнуб страницу с нужныии значениями подстановки. Еслм да то пусть js в xhr запросе отдает урл страницы и обект с параметрами вида: {{clasName: 'replaceValue'},...} Тогда пхп булет знать где и что вставлят. И возвращает резцльтат обратно в js.  Только вопрос а почему низя это парсить самим js. И откуда js знает где и на что менять, а пхп нет?